# Vector notation unclear step

Tags: economics

In my econometrics textbook, I have this step which is not clear to me:

> \begin{align} S &= e'e \\ &= (y-W\beta)'(y-W\beta) \\ &= \underbrace{y'}_{1\times T} \ \underbrace{y}_{T\times 1} -\underbrace{y'}_{1\times T} \ \underbrace{W\beta}_{(T\times2)(2\times1)} -\underbrace{\beta'W'y}_{(1\times2)(2\times T)(T\times1)} +\underbrace{\beta'W'W\beta}_{1\times1},
> \end{align}
>   or, since all the terms are scalars, $$S =y'y -2\beta'W'y +\beta'W'W\beta. \tag{2.5.6}$$

Basically, I don't understand how we go from $-y'W\beta -\beta'W'y$ to $-2\beta'W'y'$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [mathjax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 1):

$y^\prime W \beta$ is a 1 by 1 matrix (a scalar).  As such, it is equivalent to its own transpose (if you exchange rows and columns in a matrix with one row and one column, you have changed nothing).

So
$$y^\prime W \beta = (y^\prime W \beta)^\prime = \beta^\prime W^\prime y$$

Comment: Thank you, but why is _y′Wβ_ a 1by 1 matrix?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is $y′\ W\beta$ a $1$ by $1$ matrix?

If you want to evaluate the dimensions of a product you just have to look at the dimensions of the very left factor and the very right factor. The number of rows of the product is the number of the rows of the very left factor ($\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$). And the number of columns of the product is the number of the columns of the very right factor ($\color{red}{\text{red}}$)

$$\large{\underbrace{\beta'W'y}_{(\color{blue}1\times \color{green}2)(\color{green} 2\times \color{pink} T)( \color{pink} T\times \color{red}1)}} $$

The other dimensions (green, pink) are cancelling out each other.